# Elegant way to represent project state in enum

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I use a enum for describe different project states:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProjectStatus
{
   Undefined = 1 << 0,
   Closed = 1 << 1,
   Opened =1 << 2,
   ToMigrate = 1<<3 
}
```

Now, if I want to go from one state to another, I have to check if this is possible. For this I had the idea to extend my enum as follow:

```
[Flags]
public enum ProjectStatus
{
   Undefined = 1 << 0,
   Closed = 1 << 1,
   Opened = 1 << 2,
   ToMigrate = 1<<3,
   CanOpen = Opened | ToMigrate,
   CanClose = Opened,
   CanDelete = Closed | ToMigrate 
}
```

With this solution im able to check a state change:

```
if ((actualState & CanOpen) == CanOpen)
   {
      // open is allowed.
   }
```

My only problem is now, that e.g.  CanClose and Opened have the same underlying value and CanClose == Opened is true.

So my question is, if someone knows an alternative way to handle this problem in a more elegant way. (maybe with two different enum types?)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use distinct values, do not mess up them together, for example

```
public enum ProjectStatus
{
   Undefined = 1 << 0,
   Closed = 1 << 1,
   Opened = 1 << 2,
   ToMigrate = 1<<3      
}
```

And after check if the project can be closed in a *function*

```
public bool CanClose(ProjectStatus status)
{
    return (status & Opened) == Opened;
}
```

Something like this. You should definitely imrove this code, this is just an example.

In other words, move desicional logic out of enum in a functions. In enum leave only a *raw* data.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also had more or less this solution. But I thought maybe there is a more short form. Because my real ProjectStatus has about 10 states and the CanXxxx states are more complex the described above. But i think i have to live with this way :-).

Comment: @rhe1980: especially if states are complex, do not include them into enum, but use functions to make a computation.

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question directly, I don't think `CanOpen` `CanClose` should be part of `ProjectStatus`, they are properties of `Project`.

```
[Flags]
public enum ProjectStatus
{
   Undefined = 1 << 0,
   Closed = 1 << 1,
   Opened =1 << 2,
   ToMigrate = 1<<3 
}

public class Project
{
   //other properties

   public ProjectStatus Status { get; set; }

   public bool CanOpen
   {
       get 
       { 
             return this.Status == ProjectStatus.Opened 
                 || this.Status == ProjectStatus.StatusToMigrate;  
       } 
   }
}
```